# How to write a button component in VueJS 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to write a button component. My question is: if I use `vm.$emit` to send a click event, I cannot inject `$event` and other parameters into the handler like native HTML element like this

```
<button v-on:click="handler($event, 'other-parameter')" />
```

since the handler will only receive the argument passed into `vm.$emit`. One solution is to passing a function as props, but I would like the component works like a native HTML element. Could I do this? and HOW?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you? https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Methods-Events

```
methods: {
    handler($e, param) {
       $this.$emit('buttonClicked', $e, param);
    }
}
```

and in the listener

```
<component @buttonClicked="handleClick">
```

Comment: Yes, we can do that. But it means the user of the component need to use the specified handler signature. What I want to do is making a signature-free handler that user could decide whether or not to inject a event.